# Modelling a Complex Object in Redis

Tags: redis, node-redis

I am looking to use Redis as a database since it provides excellent real time data capabilities and scales better than mongo. But the data that I am using is mostly in some kind of complex json format and Redis does not easily accommodate it, given that it is primarily a key-value store.

How would I model this complex object using redis?

```
vacation : [
    {
      daysUntilVacation: 10,
      vacationType: {
        type: 'tropical',
        media: [
          {
            type : 'image',
            src  : 'http://www.hawaii.com',
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You're asking the wrong question - with Redis you need to begin with identifying your queries, and only afterwards can you model the data to be efficiently manipulated.

That said, you may want to look at ReJSON - a Redis module that implements a JSON data type:

- Blog: https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-as-a-json-store/
- Documentation: https://redislabsmodules.github.io/rejson/
- Source: https://github.com/redislabsmodules/rejson

(disclaimer: module's author here ;))

Comment: So I would want to pull that entire array. The problem that I see from messing around with redis for a day is that you can't set lists to be the value of a set/hash key. Everything is just strings. Also, I just checked out your package, apparently under "issues" theres an unresolved problem with mac compatibility which is what I develop on, otherwise it looks pretty cool.

Comment: If you want to pull the entire thing, just store it as a string. As for Mac, you may have noticed that I'm open for assistance ;)